# How do I get Eclipse to honor a pom.xml full of modules

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Using Eclipse Neon 1a Release 4.6.1, Eclipse m2e Version 1.7.0.20160603

Top level pom looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>BORA-WFM</groupId>
    <artifactId>BORA-WFM-aggregator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>Mike</module>
        <module>ike</module>
        <module>bike</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

I've run Project Context Menu Maven => Update Project... but Eclipse / maven refuses to recognize and compile the modules.

How do I make this work?

Comment: You try a force update in the Update Projects dialog?

Comment: Yes, doesn't appear to have done anything

Comment: Can you make sure that the reference to maven settings.xml and repository path are configured correctly in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is unable to honor them as IntelliJ can. You can create like a bunch of new (dependent with eachother) projects that are actually Your submodules.

There are two ways:

1.File --> Import --> General/Existing Projects into Workspace
Then You select a path being Your root project, and eclipse will detect subprojects, You can checkbox them and they will be imported

2.You can right click on a project and do Configure-->Detect Nested Projects